# How to sum last n rows conditionally in R

Tags: r

I have a very long data frame (master) like this:
(last row is what i expect to get but i couldn't figure out how to do it)

```
id      Match     Points          Team     Team/Points in last 3 matches
44631   154235      3          Nacional    4
44623   154231      3       Millonarios    3
44639   154239      1          Nacional    4
44640   154239      1            Junior    4
44637   154238      1       Millonarios    5
44670   154260      3            Junior    2
44657   154249      3          Nacional    2
44668   154258      1       Millonarios    7
44495   154149      0          Nacional    3
44685   154263      1            Junior    1
44687   154266      1          Nacional    3
44688   154266      1       Millonarios    6
44698   154265      3       Millonarios    3
44695   154264      0            Junior    1
44707   154274      1          Nacional    2
44713   154273      1          Nacional    1
44724   154281      3       Millonarios    0 
44725   154282      1            Junior    0
44737   154991      1          Nacional    0
```

And i want to create a new column (Team/Points in last 3 matches) that shows the cumulative sum of points for every team in last 3 matches.
That last row of team´s match should sum the points rised for that team in last 3 matches.

I could build the past cumulative sum of points for every team´s match, but i couldn´t figure out how to limit that sum to the three most recent matches...

This is my code:

```
>master$ptos_antes <- ave(master$points,master$teamXtourn,
                    FUN=function(x) cumsum(c(0, head(x,-1)))
)
```

`master$teamXtourn` is a key field that i made to subset last matches cumulative sum to the tournament season. Is master$id_team concatenated with master$id_tournament. It works ok to provide total points acquired for every team before every match, but now i want the same but limited to last three matches.

Comment: There are no match dates. Are the matches in chronological order? Or should the data be ordered by Match id as a time variable?

Comment: It's called a column- not a row. Also, why in the first row there 4 cumulative points already?

Comment: Yes. Therea are match dates. I´m sorry i did´nt includeed them in the data sample. Matches are sorted by date_match.

Comment: The first row shows the most recent match (match = 154235 ). 4 cumuled points are the sume of three most recent matches (matches 154239 , 154249 and 154149)

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that, by sum of points in the last three matches, you are including the points that were earned during the game in question as well. For example, if the game number is 4, you would want to sum all points from games 4, 3, 2, and 1. If this isn't the case, then change game - 3 to game - 2.

```
# create some data 
library(dplyr)
data.frame(teams = rep(c("team1", "team2", "team3"), 33),
           match_number = sample(1:1000, 99, replace = FALSE),
           points = sample(1:100, 99, replace = TRUE)) -> dat

# get the relative match numbers for each team
dat %>%
    group_by(teams) %>%
    mutate(game_num = rank(match_number)) %>%
    as.data.frame -> z

# sum the points in the last 3 games 
last3 <- function(x) {
    z[x, "teams"] -> team
    z[x, "game_num"] -> game
    game - 3 -> last_three
    if(last_three < 1) last_three <- 1
    z[z$game_num %in% last_three:game &
          z$teams == team, "points"] -> pnts
    sum(pnts) 
}

sapply(1:nrow(z), FUN = last3) -> z$points_last3
```

Comment: Great!! It is easy an quick. One thing more: If i wanted to sort matches by game_date i just need to change rank() instead the appropiated row?

Comment: if you want to sort the data after it has already been manipulated (in other words, if you want to sort the dataframe called z) then you can use the arrange function in dplyr or the order function